# zernik moments and Local binary pattern

Tags: image-processing, local-features, feature-extraction

Both of zernik moments and Local binary pattern (LBP) are feature detectors and can achieve rotation invarient.

How can they achieve rotation invarient over an image?

What are the advantages of applying zernik moments to an image?

What are the advantages of applying LBP to an image?

What is the computional cost of each one?